# Async AJAX call with lookup data using ko observableArray?

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I have an observableArray of options that gets bound to the following:

```
<select data-bind="options: lookupData.options, optionsText: 'DisplayName', optionsValue: 'Id', value: optionId" />
```

When I first apply bindings, the `options()` observable array is empty - an async AJAX call is sent to retrieve these options.

Most of the time, this works perfectly.  But if I display the view very quickly, before the AJAX call returns, the dropdown displays with a default option selected, but the options become available.  The selected option isn't updated though.

In other words - if I have 'Blue' as the currently selected option, but the select markup is displayed before the AJAX call completes, 'Blue' doesn't get selected after the observableArray of options is populated.

Am I missing some syntax to make this work?

Code:

```
   // getLookupData()
   var lookupData = {};
   lookupData.colors = ko.observableArray();
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: getAllergyRelationshipListUrl.url,
            async: true,
            data: new Object(),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
            lookupData.colors(data.Data);
        });

   return lookupData;

   // colorVm
   if (vm.colorLookupData == null) {       
      vm.colorLookupData = getLookupData();
   }

   ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Can you post your view model?

Comment: @AnthonyChu - just updated

Comment: Is this an edited version of your code? because it doesn't look complete. Would it be possible to create a jsFiddle of the view.

Answer (score 3):

It's a known problem on knockout select. Before your ajax finishes, the `value` does not exist in `options`, the `options` binding enforced your `value` to be one of `options`.

This is solved in knockout since version 3.1 with introduction of `valueAllowUnset`.

Update your binding to:

```
<select data-bind="valueAllowUnset: true, options: lookupData.options, optionsText: 'DisplayName', optionsValue: 'Id', value: optionId" />
```

You can read here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#using-valueallowunset-with-select-elements